# Удалить в строке все, что идет после третьего слеша

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

Есть ссылка https://expressjs.com/ru/. Нужно удалить все, что идет после третьего слеша (/).

Именно после слеша, т. к. ссылка меняется! Поэтому просто удалить определенное количество символов с последнего элемента строки не пойдет.

Comment: `url.split('/').slice(0, 3).join('/')`?

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: А не проще воспользоваться [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL)?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант через [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL):

```js
url = "https://expressjs.com/ru/search?=123";
newUrl = new URL(url).origin;
console.log(newUrl);
```

Вариант через обработку строки:

```js
url = "https://expressjs.com/ru/search?=123";
newUrl = url.split('/').slice(0, 3).join('/');
console.log(newUrl);
```